# Publishing message to GCP pubsub using API is time Consuming

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a node js app in mongodb cloud platform,which will be used for posting 1 million messages to a topic in GCP pubsub.Since the platform is not supporting the npm package @google-cloud/pubsub,we implemented it using the [API reference for Pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish).Upon load testing the app,I can see each message is taking 50 seconds for posting it to the topic.Ideally it should take less than 5 secs.It takes around 30 seconds for the access_token API call and 20 seconds for the message posting API call.Since each message posting is a independent event,we cannot maintain a session to store the access_token and reuse it and API_KEY authentication method is not available for GCP PubSub.Is the API method for gcp pubsub is very slow when compared to using library @google-cloud/pubsub ?.
Can anyone suggest a solution to improve performance of GCP PubSub using  APIs

Answer (score 0):

The PubSub client library are greatly optimized in several ways. The first one is the use of gRPC protocol instead of REST API. Then, there is message aggregation before a push to PubSub (500ms of wait by default). Then, there is various async mechanism to parallelize the processing.

So, a huge and great work done by the Client Library teams and hard (or expensive) to reproduce on your side. But you can, the sources are public, you can have a look to the client libraries!

The 30s for the access_token retrieval is too long. Are you sure that you haven't network issue? In any case, this token is valid for 1H. If you can reuse it in your subsequent call you will save a lot of time!